# Setting two element's position(relative) using javascript and css - Stopping them move across

Tags: javascript, css, position, element

I'm having trouble with setting 2 div's position without one of them moving to the right/left the width of the other div. They push any elements either side over by they're own width.

What I mean by this, a visual:
[image]

How can I stop this from happening, whilst keeping both of the divs relative?

EDIT:

I realize, absolute is right for what I need as found here http://css-tricks.com/absolute-positioning-inside-relative-positioning/. However... I need them to be draggable, but if the #wrapper is set to relative, then they can't be dragged. Is there a way to make the elements so that they can be draggable with the `#wrapper` being relative?

Link to example http://jsfiddle.net/QddTt/13/

Comment: Can you provide the Markup .. or create a fiddle??

Comment: @Sushanth-- I'll try, just one moment

Comment: yea, this is pretty useless w/o markup.  Why are you using JavaScript to position elements anyhow?  I mean, if there are no other options then do what you gotta do... but if it is possible through any means in CSS you should do so.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/QddTt/11/ REMOVE the div 'lol', you'll see it jump up when you press run. Now add it back in, it jumps down. Is there a way to achieve an absolute-type position without the position being based on the document?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found out the problem. My wrapper had `z-index:-99;` in there for some reason. Removing that allowed me to drag my elements when the wrapper was static.

So the main solution: setting the position to absolute for both elements.